# Is the phrase "horizon road" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality, phrases, nouns

Is the phrase "horizon road" grammatically correct, and if so, is it equal to "road to horizon"?

Comment: Did you encounter this phrase in some larger context, or did you come up with it yourself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely any compound noun at all is grammatically correct. "Horizon road", "jalousie proof", "temperature depth", "dog cat", whatever. So the only question is whether it has a commonly agreed upon meaning.

"Horizon road" is not an established term and would be taken to mean different things by different people, or would not be understood at all.

Since you have left both the context and your intention entirely unclear, it is impossible to tell what you should do. If your goal is ambiguity, be ambiguous. If your goal is perfect clarity, then be perfectly clear. If you are writing a poem, you have all sorts of leeway. If you are writing a formal report on a plane crash, then there is simply no such thing as a "horizon road". If you are naming a book, or a video game, or a dog, then *Horizon Road* is as fine as anything. In fact, then it not only doesn't need to have a meaning, it doesn't even need to be grammatical.

Comment: In fact, this is a name of the band I play, and we argued about the correctness of it.

Comment: ... Isn't acceptableness the only thing considered unacceptable when it comes to band names?